# "Hospitable transition"

Tags: nouns, adjectives, collocation

In a resignation letter, would it be right to say:

> Please let me know how I can assist to make a hospitable transition.

Specifically, does the combination "hospitable transition" make sense in this context (or at all)?

Comment: I assume you didn't mean the question mark to be part of the sentence, but in the unlikely case that you did, the question mark does not belong there.

Comment: The word 'hospitable' usually has a 'hospitality' association, but this is not necessary:  Favorable to growth and development; agreeable: a hospitable environment. (AHD) characterized by or betokening warmth and generosity toward guests or strangers: a hospitable smile. (RHKWebster's) So the use of the word here is acceptable - but you're right to flag "hospitable transition" as not really idiomatic (2 Google hits!). I'd suggest: 'Please let me know how I can help to make the transition you're making as stress-free as possible.'

Comment: *What* context?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In American English, the most commonly used idiom (especially in the context of leaving a job) would be "...a **smooth** transition."

Answer (score 0):

I do not detect any discernible context here.  Is the person you are addressing elderly, or handicapped, or new to where you live and thus might need assistance in making a successful transition?  "Hospitable transition" does not make sense, and it is not an English idiom, at least not one of which I am aware.

If you are attempting to express the thought that you want to make a transition for someone easier and more comfortable that it would be *without* assistance, then say

> Please let me know how I can assist you in making a comfortable transition.

Comment: Thanks. As TimLymington mentioned I forgot to state the context - The speaker (me) is leaving the company and is asking what can be done to ease the process, for instance: train a replacement, transfer knowledge, etc.

Answer (score -1):

No, not really. Hospitable means friendly and welcoming to strangers.

The idiom would be "a smooth transition" or "an easy transition". I wonder if you are confusing it with the word "hostile" meaning unfriendly or antagonistic. You could certainly say "a non hostile transition", and it would make sense, but probably the others are more appropriate.